# Point www and naked domain to other server

Tags: domain, web-hosting, dns-zone

I'm kind of lost with this. I've got a domain parked on a web hosting company.

The webpage is a webapp that generate too much traffic to be on a shared hosting.

On current server I manage the emails account for the same domain. I copy the web to a dedicated server and get it up and running.

How could I sent all www.domain.tld traffic to my d. server ? Because if I either go to domain.tld or www.domain.tld I land on the same page.

On CPanel I have:

domain.tld  A   
www.domain.tld  CNAME   domain.tld

So, If I get it right when I visit www it just redirect to domain.tld. Thats ok because it's all on the same server.

I could change the CNAME of www and point to my server, right? What if the visitors visit without www (naked domain?).

I'm afraid to lose mail accounts or other functions.

**Edit for clarification:**

The shared hosting provides web, ftp and mail services (among others). The website generates too much traffic for this kind of hosting so we're moving it to a box in a dedicated server. But only the web. Mails and ftp will stay on current server.

If the user types http://www.domain.com or http://domain.com it should be redirected to the new server. For the *www* changing from CNAME to A should be enough but I don't understand how *http://domain.com* should point either to www or directly to the dedicated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `CNAME` to an `A` record to point to your server.

> What if the visitors visit without www (naked domain?).

You said in your question, in at least two places, that you wanted to move the `www` subdomain.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. But if I entered domain.com will it go to my server or will be it resolved by the webhosting. I think I get the www subdomain. I have a hard time understanding the naked domain. ´domain.com´ if it is from  a webbrowser it should go to the new server (as www). I'm asking because on the zone dns panel, domain.com has SOA, NS, A, MX and TXT. I only need to move the website to other server either if the user types www or no.

Comment: @Engerlost Okay, so then you asked completely the wrong question. You don't want to move a subdomain, you want to move a web site.

Comment: It is hard for me to explain it because I don't know much about this (also english). But yes, the webhosting gives ftp, mail and web service. I want the web (http://domain.com and http://www.domain.com) to be permanently redirect to my server but keep on this the mail and such. That makes any sense to you?

Comment: @Engerlost Yeah. Probably what you want to do is move the `www` subdomain. Then run a web server on the machine the domain points to just to redirect people who access the named domain to the `www` subdomain.

Comment: So the CNAME record becomes an A record. And the current webserver should redirect all to www (which points to the other server)? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes. It can also become a `CNAME` record to the name of the machine that will house the main web server.